# Girl-Genius - who is Agatha's brother

Tags: girl-genius

In Girl Genius

> [Gil](http://girlgenius.wikia.com/wiki/Gilgamesh_Wulfenbach) [is the brother](http://haus-of-klaus.livejournal.com/25974.html) (link taken from wikia) of [Zeetha](http://girlgenius.wikia.com/wiki/Zeetha,_Daughter_of_Chump), given the explicit warnings provided by Klaus about someone who looks like Zeetha coming to kill him, the Skifandrian knowledge that Klaus has for staying awake ([link](http://girlgenius.wikia.com/wiki/Gilgamesh_Wulfenbach/Mad)), and that Skifandrians hate twins.

In the introduction to "Agatha H. and the Airship City",

> Barry heterodyne thinks to himself about the loss of the ["Son"](http://girlgenius.wikia.com/wiki/Klaus_Barry_Heterodyne) of Bill.

Given that:

> [Agatha](http://girlgenius.wikia.com/wiki/Agatha_Heterodyne) is the daughter of Bill and Lucretia

Who is her brother?  Has that been "revealed" yet?

Comment: Why are you asking? Looking for info that isn't in article you linked?

Comment: Books often have content that is not on a wiki site. Also the web comic might have had content that was not on the wiki site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only publicly known child of Bill and Lucrezia (before Agatha's story takes place) was Klaus Barry Heterodyne.

[According to the old seneschal Carson](http://www.girlgeniusonline.com/comic.php?date=20070813), he died the night the Other attacked Castle Heterodyne, crushed by falling rubble as Carson's son tried to get him out of the castle.

[image: Klaus Barry Heterodyne]

Although the events of that night have many questions about them, there's little room for doubt as to his existence and death.  Spoilers ahoy:

> Since what happened that night is a subject of extreme debate - Lucrezia was assumed kidnapped at the time, and that is now widely thought to be not true and that she in fact may have caused the events of that night - you can make arguments for just about anything happening.  It's pretty clear Carson believes what he saw however, considering his own son was lost, and Bill Heterodyne himself went nearly nuts with the loss of both his wife and son.